# Local variable in dynamic sql used as prefix and value

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I use local variable to scroll through different databases. I am trying to make current variable value appear the result set. It works ok when the variable only used as DB prefix, but when I change hardcoded DB name from

```
SET @sqlqueryNILS = 'SELECT ''A1'' AS SourceDB, NilConts FROM ' + @ODSname + '..MyTable'
```

to

```
SET @sqlqueryNILS = 'SELECT ' + @ODSname + ' AS SourceDB, NilConts FROM ' + @ODSname + '..MyTable'
```

it fails with the following error, no matter how many extra quotes I use.

```
'Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'A1'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'B2'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'C3''
```

Query:

```
CREATE TABLE #ODS_NILS(SourceDB NVARCHAR(6), NilConts INT)
CREATE TABLE A1..MyTable(NilConts INT)
INSERT INTO A1..MyTable SELECT 22
CREATE TABLE B2..MyTable(NilConts INT)
INSERT INTO B2..MyTable SELECT 24
CREATE TABLE C3..MyTable(NilConts INT)
INSERT INTO C3..MyTable SELECT 25

DECLARE @odslist TABLE (id INT IDENTITY(1,1),ODSDB NVARCHAR(20))                        
DECLARE @count INT = 1                      
DECLARE @total INT                      
INSERT INTO @odslist SELECT 'A1' UNION SELECT 'B2' UNION SELECT 'C3'                    

SELECT @total = MAX(id) FROM @odslist                       
WHILE @count <= @total                      
BEGIN                       
DECLARE @ODSname NVARCHAR(20), @sqlqueryNILS NVARCHAR(max)              
SELECT @ODSname = ODSDB FROM @odslist WHERE id = @count 


SET @sqlqueryNILS = 'SELECT ''A1'' AS SourceDB, NilConts FROM ' + @ODSname + '..MyTable'

INSERT INTO #ODS_NILS EXEC(@sqlqueryNILS)       
SET @sqlqueryNILS = NULL        
SET @count=@count+1;                
END;

SELECT * FROM #ODS_NILS
```

Comment: There is no table called `MyTable` into your script !

Comment: what's + '..MyTable'  for?

Comment: That does not actually matter since it exists in different databases, but ok, added this one.

Comment: MyTable is a source table the query is addressed to. It exists in dozen databases. I need NilConts value and database name in the result set.

Comment: so you are actually running this script FROM ' + @ODSname + '..MyTable ? or just at the @ODSname?

Comment: I run the whole string. I need the database name currently in use, which is stored in @ODSname, to appear in SourceDB column of the result set. N'SELECT does not help.

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'A1'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'B2'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'C3'

Comment: Have you tried `SET @sqlqueryNILS = 'SELECT ''' + @ODSname + ''' AS SourceDB, NilConts FROM ' + @ODSname + '..MyTable'`

Comment: Ah! thank you. I tried, but did not pay enough attention to the error message. Actual database name is longer than I allocated to SourceDB.

Answer (score 0):

sqlqueryNILS  is nvarchar so

```
SET @sqlqueryNILS = N'SELECT
```